# How to deploy a Go app using local package

Tags: go, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to upload my Go app but the problem is that I get an error because I have made modifications to the package files

The imports from Github lie in `C:\Users\Myuser\go\pkg\mod` but when I try to upload my Go App, Heroku imports from Github instead of uploading the local modified files. Is there any way to upload my local packages instead of importing them when I deploy the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try building the app with the "-mod vendor" option so it uses the vendored files instead of pulling the git dependencies

```
go build -mod vendor
```